# Comments can not contain that content

Tags: feature-request

The Stack Overflow software just rejected my comment:

[image: An error message straight from the summer of love?]

- The "specific bit of information" I wanted was where the OP was stuck, so I could explain that point rather than write his entire code for him. People tend to learn more that way ...
- The "specific improvement I tried to suggest" was that he showed where he was stuck...
- I could downvote and move on, but how are new users ever supposed to learn asking good questions, if downvotes are all the feedback they get?

Oh, and I do not *assume* they tried anything. But in case they did, I do not want to lump them together with the help vampires, because inexperience in asking questions can be fixed, and we were all newbies once.

But none of that matters, because the Stack Overflow software overruled me.

Hasn't this filter served its purpose by now? Aren't the numerous questions it prompts on meta indication enough that it creates more problems than it solves? (See, I can ask rhetorical questions, too :-)

Comment: It was not "software" that overruled you, it was a community manager that typed in the regex rule.  Probably Shog9, judging from the phrasing.  He's just talking back to you, he does not want to see the I-am-mad-as-hell email from the OP in his inbox.  Well, who does.  Customer support for a company that does not have a no-questions-asked-money-back guarantee is dicey.  Although meta seems to pull it off pretty well :)

Answer (score 8):

That filter and filters like it (for example the "what have you tried" auto-nuke pattern, currently at [550 eligible comments in the past 4 weeks](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/676447), not including ones already nuked - and I just reviewed and killed about 100 or so non-constructive ones from the past week yesterday, myself, and anecdotally I'd say about 95% of the comments I looked at were legitimately not useful) do still serve their purpose, I believe.

For one thing, you've already got an appropriate alternative for that instead of a comment: Vote to close as lacking an MCVE, too broad, or unclear, and let the instructions on the close blurb serve their purpose. On that note...

> I could downvote and move on, but how are new users ever supposed to learn asking good questions, if downvotes are all the feedback they get?

If downvotes are all the feedback they get then that's no good, that's why it's important to cast close votes when appropriate, as closures *do* attempt to give constructive feedback in the form of advice and help center links.

Also, if closing isn't your thing or you don't want to VTC for whatever reason, in 100% of the cases there are generally other ways to phrase such a comment to get past the filters.

I don't believe such comments are always bad, it's just that there are other ways to express the same thing, and also given how the "what have you tried" meme (pretty much) is still going strong, I'd say a few inconvenient blocks here and there are worth it to prevent a continued slew of the non-constructive majority.

Comment: That the filter still matches comments is not evidence for bad comments. If anything, these comments are evidence for bad questions (of the 10 most recent comments in your query, not a single one was applied to a question with positive score ...). Closing can be an alternative, but seems unnecessarily harsh if a question is otherwise good. And it is those cases where good intent, and the desire to improve, is most likely. And yes, I am aware that I can rephrase to get past the filters, but I can think of more productive uses for my creativity.

Comment: @meriton Well, the rephrasing is the important part. See, "what have you tried" by itself is not [constructive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/constructive), *but* some really simple changes make it legitimately constructive. For example: *"There's a few different solutions to your problem, but in order to prevent answerers from accidentally spending time writing answers you've already tried, can you include a short list of any attempts you've made so far, if any?"* [This can be really helpful](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116) for saving time, too. *That's* the purpose of the filters.

Comment: @meriton - Closure prevents a question that can't/wont' be fixed from getting answered, which is in everyone's best interest, including the OP. But if you don't want to bother figuring out a comment that won't get blocked, just copy/paste the appropriate close reason as a comment. I do this frequently and include a link to the help center (sometimes bolding the part of the debug close reason that's relevant).

Comment: @meriton As for evidence; yeah, this is the best I can do. I know when Shog9 was doing that "-1" filter he was able to pull a list of attempted comments that were blocked, but I'm not sure if that was some quick temporary debugging thing he implemented just for that, or if SE always tracks all blocked comments. That info isn't accessible to us but if a CM sees this they may be able to pull a true list of blocked comments. Fwiw, I only use the existing comments as evidence that people still *leave* those comments, not that they are bad. The "bad" is just anecdotal from the ~100 reviews I did.

Comment: @meriton Oh yeah, also, in addition to the script I linked above, [you may find these shortcuts helpful as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/230261).